# my sitemap.xml is taking forever to load

Tags: php, html, xml

So I made a php script which just reads pages from database (around 25k URLs) and writes them to sitemap.xml in root directory of website.

XML file size is 4.6mb

When I try to open the sitemap.xml, I get no errors, but it just takes like 3-4 minutes to load it in my browser. I'm just trying to load and see how it came out.

I used some web xml validator which points to the URL and it said it is valid and without errors, so that's not the issue.

I'm just worried that, with the long load times, it might throw search engines off? I mean, 4.5mb should download within 10 seconds!

Comment: What are the specs of the server? And as far as I'm concerned it will not throw search engines off. At least, not Google. The max size for this is 10mb. Have a look at http://www.arnebrachhold.de/2006/04/07/google-sitemaps-faq-sitemap-issues-errors-and-problems/#P28_maxsize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loading time is probably due to either

- Your internet connection
- The servers upstream speed

4.5 is a massive sitemap, i'm wondering if you needs such big sitemap.
What you could to is split it up in multiple sitemaps and use a [sitemap index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemap_index)

Recalling your comment below it could be that generating the Sitemap out of that huge amount of data takes up alot of time. It has to fetch it from a database i guess this takes time.
Try to save the sitemap after loading it, then upload that "standalone" file of the sitemap. See if that loads faster. If so then your script is lagging the loading process.

Comment: Well we have alot of inventory, so each item gets a separate URL. Think eBay style on a much smaller scale though. Am I wrong for doing it this way? Also it's not my Internet conn, and my site and server work blazing fast(yahoo web hosting(yeah I know not a good pick)), minus this case

Comment: Make the script so it seperates like catagories of items. Then generate a sitemap index like shown above. This way you generate like X smaller sitemaps that are read by search engines through the index file. Look at the link above

Comment: Added a part to the answer!

Comment: Sitemap is made with a completely separate php script using fopen to make the file. so by the time it becomes an xml, theres absolutley no loading. From a database. So you are saying make multiple site maps based on different inventory categories? That is probably possible with some fiddling.

Comment: Your sitemap is created with a cron or do you call upon a script that then generates an XML?

Comment: I just use a php page/script, such as makesitemap.php to write the xml file. when I load that web page,  it renews the sitemap.

Comment: it must have to do with the fact that there is just so much text. I downloaded the file onto my desktop(took 1 second with broadband connection) and it opened but the text kept loading and loading.

Comment: why don't you make a cron that refreshes the sitemap every X. then search engines wil just call the xml it self.